# How to mock a module wide extension method with mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, kotlin, mockito

**This is the method to test:** 
It gets an URL and return a json after sending a GET request. It is a plain function which sits in a package rather than a method from a class. Same case for the extension method below.

```
fun getJson (url: String): String {
    val connection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    connection.requestMethod = "GET"
    return connection.getResult()
}
```

**This is the extension method:** 
It will start connecting and read from result stream.

```
internal fun HttpURLConnection.getResult(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): String {
    this.connect()
    return this.inputStream.bufferedReader(charset).use { it.readText() }
}
```

**This is the test case:** 
I tried to mock the `HttpURLConnection` that is about to be used here and call the original method, then just call the method and assert whether the mock has been set with the expected value.

```
class Spike {
    @Test
    fun test_getJson() {
        val expectedResult = "{ok: true}"
        val mockConnection = mock(HttpURLConnection::class.java)
        Mockito.`when`(mockConnection.getResult()).thenReturn(expectedResult)

        getJson("http://www.google.com")

        assertEquals("GET", mockConnection.requestMethod)
        assertEquals("http://www.google.com", mockConnection.url.host)
    }
}
```

**This is the error**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: this.inputStream must not be null    at
>   my.spike.pack.http.UtilsKt.getResult(utils.kt:45)

It just like the mock is not working.

How to solve this without changing the signature of the `getJson` function?

Comment: Thanks for the note. More clear now! That doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because of the way Kotlin extension methods are implemented on the class / bytecode level.

What you see in source code is `HttpURLConnection.getResult` but on the class/bytecode level there is another file created with a static method: `public final static getResult(HttpURLConnection, Charset)`.

Mockito cannot mock static methods. If you really have to mock one, then I think [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) is capable of doing that.

Edit:
If you have a module wide function then it is also generated on a class. Assuming you have a file `StreamFunctions.kt` with a function: `doSomething` then, there will be (by default) generated class `StreamFunctionsKt` with a static function `doSomething`. More details can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Comment: Really thanks, and what about a module-wide function, which is just a function sit in a module without reside in a class, can mockito mock that?

Answer (score 0):

That should be as easy as

```
    Mockito.`when`(mockConnection.inputStream).thenReturn(ByteArrayInputStream("test".toByteArray()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still, it gives the same error. :(